# Number of Zeros in the binary representation of an Integer

Tags: c, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best algorithm to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Given a 32-bit integer N,Devise an algorithm to find the number of zeros in the binary bit representation of N.

The simplest algorithm I can think of is to check the binary representation for Zeros,in C something like this:

```
int num_of_zero(int num)
 {
   if(0 == num) return 1; /*For the input 0 it should output 1 */
   int Count = 0;
   while(num>0){
     if(0 == (num&1)) Count++;
    num >>= 1;
}
return Count;
}
```

I was wandering if there is some algorithm to compute at constant time.

For input **0** it should return 1 **not 32**.

For **5** the output should be 1.As binary representation is **101**.

For **7** the output should be 0.

Precisely,I am looking for a better algorithm to compute number of (non-leading) zeros in the binary interpretation of an 32 bit integer.Hope the problem is clear now.

**Edit:** As pointed Alex Martelli,delroth I am modifying my code to made it more readable & using iteration this time.

Comment: Duplicate.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer

Comment: num_of_zero(num >> 1);
   if(!(num & 1))Count++;

can you break that down ? I cant see how that'll work. Am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of marking homework until the OP has had a chance to answer the query. There is ample precedent on SO for people who were self-learning. And, if it *is* homework and they use a solution found verbatim off the net, they'll almost certainly be failed anyway for plagiarism (if their educators have even a modicum of intelligence).

Comment: @nthrgeek, if this *is* homework, please tag it so.

Comment: Oh, and I don't believe this is technically a duplicate - that reference one asked for one bits which is subtly different - you cannot use the trick of stopping early when the value is zero since, as @AlexM points out in his excellent answer, you miss out on the leading zeros.

Comment: Can be solved with the Hamming count because `num_of_zero(n) == NumberOfSetBits(~n)`. Equivalent problem, but a slightly different statement of it.

Comment: @paxdiablo: No it's not an home work problem,I am looking for some better algorithm as this is O(n).

Comment: @ ChrisInEdmonton : Well,howz this problem is duplicate ?!! I am looking for number of non-leading clear bits not set bits.

Comment: Well, when this discussion started, you hadn't specified "non-leading," which makes this a slightly different problem.

Comment: Sorry but I tried to edit the problem that time only,but stackoverflow crashed.

Comment: Huh !! Exact duplicate ?!! I was looking for number of no leading zeros not number of set bits !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple way to do this is to iterate over each bit of the binary representation of the number, test the value of each bit, and count up how many of them are zero.  A loop would be much clearer than recursion for this.

There are many more optimized methods for doing this, though.  You can find some of the better ones in answers to this question, ["Best algorithm to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer) (obviously, the number of zero bits is the number of set bits subtracted from the total number of bits).

Comment: This is simpler & I am aware of it,any better algorithm ? Like the one we have for set bits ?

Comment: You can use any of those algorithms, since the sum of the number of set bits and the number of unset bits is the total number of bits.  If you want to know the number of non-leading zeroes, you can us the log-base-2 of the number to determine the index of the highest set bit; there are algorithms for finding this quickly too.

Comment: The Bit Twiddling Hacks website, which Suppressingfire references in his answer, has a number of ways to find the log-base-2:  http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious

Comment: Thanks & +1 for letting me know about the log-base-2 thing :).But Can you please help me understand how does that help to reduce the complexity in this problem ?

Comment: The number of non-leading zeros in an unsigned int N is the same as the number of bits set in [ ((2^(lg2(N))-1) & (~N) ].

Answer (score 6):

There's a great resource online called [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) that contains all sorts of great little C tricks. You may be particularly interested in the [Counting bits set](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive) section.

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dumb way -- there are more exotic implementations in the duplicate question, but I have used something similar to this without much ill effect in the past.

We use a table of nibbles here to reduce the number of times the loop is run -- if you're doing a boatload of these computations, it might be more efficient to build a much bigger array, say, at the byte level, cutting the loop runs in half.

```
/* How many bits are set in every possible nibble. */
static size_t BIT_TABLE[] = {
    0, 1, 1, 2,     /* 0, 1, 2, 3 */
    1, 2, 2, 3,     /* 4, 5, 6, 7 */
    1, 2, 2, 3,     /* 8, 9, A, B */
    2, 3, 3, 4      /* C, D, E, F */
};

size_t num_of_bits(int num) {
    /* Little reworking could probably shrink the stack space in use here. */
    size_t ret = 0, i;
    register int work = num;

    /* Iterate every nibble, rotating the integer in place. */
    for(i = 0; i < (sizeof(num) * 2); i++) {
        /* Pointer math to get a member of the static array. */
        ret += *(BIT_TABLE + (work & 0xF));
        work >>= 4;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is definitely overkill -- and besides, your code's quite buggy (it will not count any of the *leading* zeros of `num`!!!).  A simple iteration, such as:

```
int num_of_zero(int num) {
  unsigned int unum = (unsigned int)num;
  int count;
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    if(!(unum & 1)) ++count;
    unum >>= 1;
  }
  return count;
}
```

is correct and faster (can be coded more concisely, but I think this is the clearest expression).

If you have to do this computation many times, consider precomputing an array of (say) 256 "counts of zeros" (each value giving the count for its index, 0 to 255 included, as an 8-bit number).  Then you can loop just 4 times (masking and shifting 8 bits at a time), and easily unroll the loop -- if your compiler's not smart enough to do it on your behalf;-).

Comment: Thanks,I don't want to count any leading zeros.

Comment: Interesting how you totall and drastically changed your specs in your question's edit -- wouldn't it have been nicer to express the **right** specs in the first place?!  Plus, if you don't want to count **any** leading zeros, as you now say, how can the result for 0 be 1, as you now claim it should be in your recent edit of your answer?  That zero you want to count _is_ "leading".  Guess you'll have to specialcase that one weird outlier -- the one and only case in which you **do** want to count a leading 0!-)  Apart from that, `while(unum)` as the loop instead of `for` &c will work fine.

Comment: Sorry,but I tried to edit the question at that time only,but I was getting 503 Error everytime!!

Comment: Yeah, I had a long spell of 500's too.  Anyway, yes, it ends up similar, cleansed of other absurdities besides recursion, such as that `static`.

Comment: Strangely enough my comment vanished ?!! But surely thanks :)

Comment: As pointed by you & some other I had modified my code,I hope there is no problem now :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that this is a homework question.  No problem!  Here's the fastest possible solution (after a long startup cost):

Make an array of `byte` that is 2<sup>32</sup> long.  Precompute the value of the number of zeros in the binary representation for each possible `int` value to fill in that array.  From then on, you'll have an array that will give you the number of zeros per value.

Yes, that solution is silly -- it's a lot of work for little gain -- but combine it with one other idea:

What happens if you just precompute the values that are 8 bits long?  Would you be able to write code that, though not quite as fast, would still return the number of 0-bits in a int?

What happens if you just precompute the values that are 4 bits long?  2 bits long?  1 bit long?

I hope this gives you ideas for a better algorthm...

Comment: Crikey, a 4 billion byte array. I was about to downvote this until I saw where you were going :-)

Comment: I wrote this comment when the question first came out.  Stackoverflow crashed before I submitted it.  When I returned, others had answered the question, too.  I wanted my answer to still show up.  And, yeah, paxdiablo -- the original answer IS silly.  But I had hoped that it would give some better ideas.

Comment: Maybe SO crashed because it ran out of memory trying to compute the 4-gig lookup table... :-)  Anyway, I thought this was a good answer (+1).

Answer (score 1):

It is not really an answer to your main question, but you should rewrite your recursive function like this :

```
int num_of_zero(int num)
{
    int left_part_zeros;

    if (num == 0)
        return 0;

    left_part_zeros = num_of_zero(num >> 1);
    if ((num & 1) == 0)
        return left_part_zeros + 1;
    else
        return left_part_zeros;
}
```

Your implementation have a lot of problems, beside being completely unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found was to base it on something that counts the ones then simply subtract that from 32 (assuming that you're *sure* the `int` size is 32 bits).

```
int numberOfOnes (int num) {
    int count = 0;
    unsigned int u = (unsigned int)num;
    while (u != 0) {
        if ((u&1) == 1)
            count++;
        u >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}
int numberOfZeros (int num) {
    return 32 - numberOfOnes (num);
}
```

This actually gives you both variants (ones and zeros) - there are faster ways to do it but I wouldn't consider them unless and until you know there's a performance problem. I tend to code for readability first.

You may also want to at least test the possibility that a table lookup could be faster (the prime directive of optimisation is *measure, don't guess!*

One possibility there could be replacing the `numberOfOnes` function with something that operates a nybble at a time:

```
int numberOfOnes (int num) {
    static const count[] = {
        0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4
    };
    int retval = 0;
    unsigned int u = (unsigned int)num;
    while (u != 0) {
        retval += count[u & 0x0f]
        u >>= 4;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: If this is what I am  looking for I would better use while(num) { count++;num &=(num - 1) } For computing the number of set-bits.